# How to reset one Bootstrap Multiselect when another Bootstrap Multiselect is used via jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using the Bootstrap-Multiselect (http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)

I have two dropdowns, when an item is selected in one dropdown I need to reset the other dropdown. I have been attempting to do this using the onchange jQuery but without success.

If an option is selected from dropdown1, then deselect/reset everything in dropdown2.

```
<form>
    <select id="dropdown1" name="dropdown1" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
```

If an option is selected from dropdown2, then deselect/reset everything in dropdown1.

```
    <select id="dropdown2" name="dropdown2" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

My failed jQuery

```
$("#dropdown1").change(function () {
    $('#dropdown2').multiselect('refresh');
});

$("#dropdown2").change(function () {
    $('#dropdown1').multiselect('refresh');
});
```

How should this be accomplished?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect you need to reset the select element and then do the refresh, like so:

```
$("#dropdown1").change(function () {
    $('#dropdown2 option:selected').each(function() {
        $(this).prop('selected', false);
    })
    $('#dropdown2').multiselect('refresh');
});

$("#dropdown2").change(function () {
    $('#dropdown1 option:selected').each(function() {
        $(this).prop('selected', false);
    })
    $('#dropdown1').multiselect('refresh');
});
```

That code is borrowed from the reset button code on the Bootstrap Multiselect site. See the [further examples](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#further-examples)

Comment: No problem. You were nearly there.

Answer (score 9):

Another way of deselecting all options. (Because multiselect('refresh') did not work for me.)

```
$('#ID').multiselect('deselectAll', false);    
$('#ID').multiselect('updateButtonText');
```

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me.

```
$('#ID').val('').multiselect('refresh');
```